# How to load html in AccompanistWebViewClient using jetpack compose

Tags: android, html, webview

How to load html in AccompanistWebViewClient using  jetpack compose

```
val webViewClient = remember {
        object : AccompanistWebViewClient() {
}
}
val chromeViewClient = remember {
        object : AccompanistWebChromeClient() {
            override fun onCloseWindow(window: WebView?) {
                super.onCloseWindow(window)
            }
        }
    }

val html = rememberWebViewState(html)
    WebView(
        state = html,
        onCreated = { webView ->
            webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
        },
        client = remember { webViewClient },
        chromeClient = remember { chromeViewClient }
    )
```

but it's not loaded html,
shows Webpage not available

Comment: Have you tried `rememberWebViewStateWithHTMLData`?